# Technique to remove factor structure from panel data

Tags: r, pca, covariance, panel-data

Let's say I have panel data (i.e. time-series data and cross-sectional).

Factors drive the bulk of the data as well as some noise.

Naturally I can express this factor structure using a covariance matrix - or a set of eigenvectors and corresponding eigenvalues.

I would like to create a new panel dataset that has some particular (or all) factors removed (i.e. de-factored). What's a good way to do this in R? My preference is to use factor analysis rather than PCA.

Comment: It sounds like you may be interested in [dynamic factor analysis](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=dynamic+factor+analysis&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=).